# How to make a dynamic navigation bar that changes its content based on events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

For an example i want to create a `nav bar` that contains `Log in` and `Sign up` buttons but when a user is logged in i want instead the `nav bar` to contains `Profile` button with an image thumbnail of the user and a `Sign out` button.

So what are the approaches and best practices to achieve that?

Note: i do not know whether this is achieved by front end frameworks or not
but if yes lets assume i am using `reactJS` runs with `expressJS`.

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: This is a very broad question to ask. You would be better off doing some research into a particular framework - maybe go read some reactjs documentation or tutorials. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either front-end with AJAX call or back-end, but I recommend you doing it back-end so you do not render unncessary HTML-JS code.

Basically what you have to do is to see where in your Framework (I haven't ever worked with neither expressJs nor reactJS) the user log in data is stored, and if there is a variable that tells you whether the user is authenticated.

Then you have to create a template that is called as a view from the controller and receives info on whether the user is logged in or not (in Django for example you can pass variables from the views.py to the template)

You have to create a `if` clause that evaluates the Boolean where you indicate whether the user is authenticated, and render different pieces of HTML/CSS depending on that.

You have to include this inside your navbar and prepare something like

```
{% if user_logged_in %}
<html code for logged in user with profile picture and all that>
{% else %}
<html code with login buttons>
{% endif %}
```

I am using django-template language but I am sure there is a specific way of writing it in your case.

You can also do that in the  tag to load different css files or scripts.

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be to keep a boolean flag - **isLoggedIn** in the NavBar component state. Based on which you can decide to render either Login & Sign Up Or Profile & Sign Out.

You can refer this to understand conditional rendering in React.js - https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html